# Can we execute more than one programs in code:blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

SO I am writing a program and writing my code in the main.c file of the project I created.But if I want to sample test some code or function I cannot do so.

I tried adding a new file in the project but it automatically executes the main.c file.

Isn't there a way where I can run my codes in a different place without disturbing the code in the main.c file

Comment: In another project? Make a project specifically for testing small things.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok so I made another project and executed the small code but now I can't go back to executing my main code

Comment: @Lundin I don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options for doing this:

Run two instances of Code::Blocks:

- From IDE, uncheck `Settings -> Environment -> Allow only one running instance`
- ...Or from command line: `codeblocks --multiple-instance &`

Create tool to allow target to run detached

- From IDE: Use `Tools -> Configure tools -> User-defined tools` to create a new tool, for example call it `exe_tester` as shown in example image below. (this name is arbitrary)  ***Note***: The `exe` must have already been built.   Use the `...` navigate button to navigate to the actual location of the exe, and select the `.exe` (eg. it may be in `C:\codeblocks\test\test.exe`)  This will be the actual executable that will run detached.
- Note that working directory is optional, I do not normally use it.  But experiment, it may be useful for what you want to do.
- To run the tool, Go back to `Tools` menu, and you should see `exe_tester`.  Click it and the `.exe` it is pointing to will launch *detached* from the IDE:

[image]

More on [Code::Blocks Tools](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Tools%2B_reference)

Comment: Actually your first-half of the solution was enough,but I did try the next part which gives me some error.Can you actually tell me how to do so detached

Comment: @Xtense - I added some edits to make the steps for section _Create tool..._ clear

Answer (score 0):

Create two different projects, then add all files except the different mains to both projects. Example:

Project 1:

```
C:\something\abc.h
C:\something\abc.c
C:\something\xyz.h
C:\something\xyz.c
C:\something\release\main.c
C:\something\release\project1 // the actual IDE project file
```

Project 2:

```
C:\something\abc.h
C:\something\abc.c
C:\something\xyz.h
C:\something\xyz.c
C:\something\test\main.c
C:\something\test\project2 // the actual IDE project file
```